# HOW TO: Two different jQuery on the same page - The page to be included has the newest jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a page to be PHP included anywhere at wish, and that page uses jQuery 1.4.4.
(I'll make it use even 'newest' from the official jQuery librarys source but...)
The thing that I cannot control is the version of the user's-website jQuery library.
Or even if the user have jQuery at all.

I've made some tests and including my page into sites that have OLDER jQuery - and there comes to a conflict.

This is an example of the script to be included. I can't make this work:

....php codes....

....html head.....

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  var jQ144 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQ144(document).ready(function($){

    $(".helpPlease").hover(function(){      
        $(this).animate({height:'250px'}, { queue:false, duration:400 });
        },function(){       
        $(".helpPlease").animate({height:'17px'}, { queue:false, duration:400 });
    });
```

...(the upper code is just for example)...more codes........

```
});
</script>
```

It just won't work.

Is there any way to check if the page have already jQuery? And if older - to activate the newer code - the my page's Jquery library ??
Or... how to just make the newer 'overwrite' the older one??

Or am I doing something wrong? I tried many suggestions described all over the web but with no results.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you include jQuery, it takes the `$` variable *and* creates the `jQuery` class. `$` happens to be a reference to jQuery. So when you include an older/different version of jQuery, it's actually "overwriting" (replacing) the jQuery class.

Tested, this works: (remove the `true` parameter in noConflict call)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.noConflict(  )
            jQuery144 = jQuery
            console.log(jQuery144, jQuery)
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery144(function($) {
                console.log("hello", $.fn.jquery)
            })
            jQuery(function($) {
                console.log("world", $.fn.jquery)
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT 2: There's an important issue that you'll need to have in mind. Internally, jQuery refers to itself as `window.jQuery`. When you include jQuery again, you're redefining `window.jQuery`, but the calls made in the first version, are binded in runtime, not in definition time, so it's possible that some internal calls of the oldest jQuery version will being actually made in the newest one. Be aware.

Comment: Gracias Gonzalo. Hmm may you please explain, looks great but, as I said: I do not know what library is waiting out there for my page. Let's assume that my page have the latest Jquery from the the jQuery site, how to make that work? I repeat. I cannot touch and I do not know what is the jQuery script out there. And there should be no conflict at all. For now, if my page have NO jQ - it works great on any page that have jQ (not if there is none), but if my page have the latest jQ: the outer page gets broken. ...

Comment: If you ensure to use functions that internally doesn't reference to window.jQuery, you should include your jQuery version (the newest one) first and then the rest of the code.
Otherwise, you can donwload the last jQuery version, and replace all the "jQuery" occurrences to another var, and then you'll be sure that all will work fine. But when you want to update jQuery, you'll have to do the work again :-) Oh, and think about plugins too.

Comment: SOLVED! WOW WOW WOW !!! yes! I reviewed all my pages and changed as you said. the TRUE parameter in the noConflict call was messing all around! Now it works! here is a reminder: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict(  )
    jQuery144 = jQuery
</script> <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery144(document).ready(function($){ 
$(function() {
$("form.logForm #submitLog").click(function() {......` codes...codes...codes.   THANKS! you saved the Earth! ;)